# For loop in Adobe ExtendScript

Tags: javascript, loops, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

my for-loop in the "setEase" function won't increase "i"

```
function storeKeyframes(){
            var properties      = app.project.activeItem.selectedProperties;
            var activeProperty  = null;
            var keySelection    = null;
            var curKey          = null;
            var curKeyTime      = null;
            var curKeyIndex     = null;

            var theEase         = new KeyframeEase(0 , slider_1_slider.value);

            for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){
                activeProperty = properties[i];
                setEase();
            }

            function setEase(){
                for (var i = 0; i < activeProperty.selectedKeys.length ; i++){
                    keySelection    = activeProperty.selectedKeys;
                    curKey          = keySelection[i];
                    curKeyTime      = activeProperty.keyTime(curKey);
                    curKeyIndex     = activeProperty.nearestKeyIndex(curKeyTime);

                    activeProperty.setInterpolationTypeAtKey(curKeyIndex, KeyframeInterpolationType.BEZIER, KeyframeInterpolationType.BEZIER);
                    activeProperty.setTemporalEaseAtKey(curKeyIndex,theEase, theEase);
                }
            }
        }
```

I just can't figure out why. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and indeed "i" is not increasing, but for me the reason was that there was an error.

The main reason for error is that the 2nd and 3rd arguments to setTemporalEaseAtKey() should be **arrays** of KeyframeEase, not just KeyframeEase (see the scripting guide).
Another reason is that activeProperty needs not be an actual Property, hence querying activeProperty.selectedKeys.length will throw an error.

On a side note, what you call curKeyIndex is actually the same as curKey, so you dont need the nearestKeyIndex stuff. The following code works for me:

```
function storeKeyframes(){
    var comp = app.project.activeItem;
    if (!comp || comp.typeName !== "Composition") return;
    var properties = comp.selectedProperties;
    var i, I=properties.length;
    var ease1 = new KeyframeEase(0,100);

    for (i=0; i<I; i++){
        if (properties[i] instanceof Property) setEase(properties[i], ease1);
        };
    };
function setEase(property, ease1){
    var ease = property.propertyValueType===PropertyValueType.Two_D ? [ease1, ease1] : (property.propertyValueType===PropertyValueType.Three_D ? [ease1, ease1, ease1] : [ease1]);
    var keySelection = property.selectedKeys;
    var i, I=keySelection.length;
    for (i=0; i<I; i++){
        property.setInterpolationTypeAtKey(keySelection[i], KeyframeInterpolationType.BEZIER, KeyframeInterpolationType.BEZIER);
        property.setTemporalEaseAtKey(keySelection[i], ease, ease);
        };
    };
storeKeyframes();
```

Comment: thak you very much, setting the ease as an array actually did the job! properties[i] only can be an instanceOf Property since I am only selecting properties at the very top for my properties variable ("app.project.activeItem.selectedProperties")

Comment: Be aware that selectedProperties can contain some propertyGroups, and sometimes selecting keyframable properties also selects the parent(s) of the initially selected properties (eg in Masks or Effects). Hence you have to filter a bit .

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Take a look into the console of the ESTK. I would suggest passing your activeProperty to your setEase function. So you keep your scopes clean.
Also it is better to not use the same iterator.

```
function main() {
  storeKeyframes();

}
function storeKeyframes() {
  var properties = app.project.activeItem.selectedProperties;
  for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    activeProperty = properties[i];
    $.writeln(i + " in storeKeyframes");
    setEase(activeProperty);
  }
  function setEase(ap) {
    for (var j = 0; j < ap.selectedKeys.length; j++) {
      $.writeln(j + " in setEase");
    }
  }
}
main();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I will give it a try when I am home